# About C Visit UK visa

Tags: visas

I have C Visit type for UK visa valid to 28/7/2016. It's a multiple entry. I already visited UK last month participating in a conference. So all my documents that I submitted were for the conference reason. And I showed the officer in LHR the invitation letter from the conference. Now I want to revisit UK with my family as a tourist at first week of next July. So is this visa will be OK to enter UK once again?